# Checking whether a bunch of intervals are overlapping

Tags: python, python-2.7, ironpython

I don't know what to search for... What is a nice way to check whether a bunch of intervals are not overlapping?

Everything is fine:

```
a, b = 0.2, 0.3
c, d = 0.4, 0.6
e, f = 0.9, 1.0
```

Not good:

```
a, b = 0.2, 0.3
c, d = 0.25, 0.5
```

Evil²:

```
a, b = 0.2, 0.3
c, d = 0.4, 0.6
e, f = 0.1, 0.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the intervals by start value (if they're just 2-tuples this is automatic) and iterate through the list, ensuring that the end value of one is always less than (or equal to, depending on your problem) the start value of the next.

```
intervals = [(0.2, 0.3),
             (0.8, 1.0),
             (0.4, 0.6),
             (0.32, 0.38)]

intervals = sorted(intervals)
disjoint = all(intervals[i+1][0] > intervals[i][1] for i in range(len(intervals) - 1))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's nice. I used  `all(e < s for (_, e), (s, _) in zip(intervals, intervals[1:]))` though.

Comment: @marcus that's very elegant.